# SendGrid not delivering the email?

Tags: c#, sendgrid

I have written a wrappper service around sendgrid and all of the pieces work except for the actual sending of the email.

service:

```
public class SendGridService : ISendGridService
    {
        public async Task Send(Email email)
        {
            var preparedEmail = PrepareEmail(email);
            var apiKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sendGridApiKey"];

            var transportWeb = new Web(apiKey);
            await transportWeb.DeliverAsync(preparedEmail);

        }

        //other methods that prepare the email
    }
```

Test class I am using to see if the email is sent:

```
[Test]
    public void Send_ShouldSendEmailToOneAddress()
    {
        //arrange
        //uses NBuilder to mock the object
        var email = Builder<Email>.CreateNew()
            .With(x => x.Recipient = "me@me.com")
            .With(x => x.Sender = "me@me.com")
            .With(x => x.SenderName = "me")
            .With(x => x.FilePathAttachement = null)
            .With(x => x.Html = null)
            .Build();

        //act
        var temp = _sut.Send(email);


        //assert

    }
```

I realize the test isnt acually testing anything but I was hoping to see the email in my inbox and then write true false tests around the code.

I never recieve an email is the problem. What am I missing to make the email actually send.

Comment: If you log into send grid is anything being received/processed by sendgrid?

Comment: What does your `DeliverAsync` method look like?

Comment: @cal5barton No, As far as SendGrid goes nothing is happening

Comment: @X3074861XThat is not my method. It comes with the SendGrid API

Comment: Are you getting successful api calls from sendgrid?

Comment: @cal5barton No, At the moment, sendgrid's service is never being called. I am able to populate the object sendgrid needs for delivery, but nothing is happening on the site or the api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling your async method correctly. in the context of a unit test it should be:

```
[Test]
public async Task Send_ShouldSendEmailToOneAddress()
{
    //arrange
    //uses NBuilder to mock the object
    var email = Builder<Email>.CreateNew()
        .With(x => x.Recipient = "me@me.com")
        .With(x => x.Sender = "me@me.com")
        .With(x => x.SenderName = "me")
        .With(x => x.FilePathAttachement = null)
        .With(x => x.Html = null)
        .Build();

    //act
    await _sut.Send(email);


    //assert

}
```

Namely:

1) change your test to return `async Task` instead of `void`

2) `await` your async method

When you use your mail sender in your program proper you need to ensure your usage of `async/await` is ['all the way down'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14528135/224410)

Comment: This gives me a compiler error: Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed variable where I am assigning the system under Test to temp.

Comment: @Robert amended.. just remove `temp` (your `SendGridService` doesnt return anything)