# ConfigureAwait(false) in F#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, f#, async-await, async-workflow

I am using a library which has been written in C# and uses the async/await pattern. In C# I can await something by calling it with `ConfigureAwait(false)` but when I use the library from F# I don't see a way of doing the same thing?

Currently I do `SomeMethodAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask` to convert it into an `Async` F# workflow, but how can I do the same as `ConfigureAwait(false)` from F# as well when calling `SomeMethodAsync`?

---

EDIT:

With some awesome help in the F# Slack channel and some additional googling I found a good explanation of how to switch context here: http://tomasp.net/blog/async-non-blocking-gui.aspx/

Comment: Why exactly do you want to not continue on captured context? What's the larger problem?

Comment: It is good practice for library code as far as I understand. This explains is well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526377/why-does-this-async-action-hang

Comment: Doesn't `SomeMethodAsync().ConfigureAwait(false) |> Async.AwaitTask` work for you?

Comment: No unfortunately not, because ConfigureAwait(false) returns an awaitable instead of a task

Comment: Actually I found the solution. Someone pointed me to this: http://tomasp.net/blog/async-non-blocking-gui.aspx/

Comment: you can post that solution as answer and accept it :)

Comment: There is nothing relevant in Petricek's blog post that I can see. Are you confusing `await` with `ConfigureAwait` perhaps? Awaiting is done with `await`, *not* with `ConfigureAwait`. ConfigureAwait controls whether the original synchronization context is restored or not. It's just a function accapting a Task and returning another. You can call it just like any other function

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos My understanding is that ConfigureAwait let's me control if it should synchronise back to the UI thread or not and Petricek has described the same thing by using `SwitchToThreadPool` in F#. Is this right or am I missing something? At least his solution seems to have fixed my issue that I had.

Comment: @dustinmoris, if you found the answer, please post it below as an answer.  It could be helpful to other people besides just you.  Me, for instance, who came here looking for the answer to this same question.

Answer (score 2):

It's as simple as calling ConfigureAwait before converting it to an F# Task.

```
SomeMethodAsync().ConfigureAwait(false) |>  Async.AwaitTask
```

However, if you are mostly dealing with C# async tasks. It's cleaner to us the [TaskBuilder.fs](https://github.com/rspeele/TaskBuilder.fs) computation expression. Available in nuget using `dotnet add package TaskBuilder.fs`.

You don't have to manually call `ConfigureAwait(false)` instead just

```
open FSharp.Control.Tasks.V2.ContextInsensitive
```

And then every time you `let!` it will automatically be `.ConfigureAwait(false)`