# Async functionality is not completing, however I get no error message

Tags: c#, http, asynchronous, async-await

**Background**

Currently creating a web api which will need to talk to another web api which I have created.  This problematic web api is out the box and the only changed I have mad is to enable cores and added two classes to it.

**Problem**

Currently this web api is executing all the way to my integration point however when it hits  `HttpResponseMessage hrm = await hc.GetAsync(requestUrl);` it stops and does not give me an error.  I tried putting a try catch on that function however it ignores that try catch aswell.  The following code will show how I am building this web api.

**Code**

**Controller**

```
    [Route("api/WorkingPaperServices/CreateWorkingPaper")]
    public IHttpActionResult CreateWorkingPaper()
    {
        try
        {
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
            bool complete = WorkingPaperCreator.StartWPCreation().Result; 
            return Ok("Finished");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("EmailLogger").Error(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ex));
            return ResponseMessage(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Not Laoded"));
        }              
    }
```

**WorkingPaperCreator - class**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;

namespace CWAppServices.Services
{
    public class WorkingPaperCreator
    {
        public static async Task<bool> StartWPCreation()
        {
            try
            {
                var testing = await IntergrationPoints.GetClientInformation();
                return true;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

**IntergrationPoints -  class (Where my problem is)**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;

namespace CWAppServices.Services
{
    public class IntergrationPoints
    {
        public static async Task<bool> GetClientInformation()
        {
            List<string> uniqueID = new List<string>();
            try
            {              
                string requestUrl = "http://appdev.tenant.com/caseware32/api/DataServices/GetAllClients";

                var action = new HttpMethod("GET");

                HttpClient hc = new HttpClient();

                HttpResponseMessage hrm = await hc.GetAsync(requestUrl);

                if (hrm.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // TODO Log 
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526377/why-does-this-async-action-hang

Comment: `catch(Exception ex){return false;}` is *very* dangerous code. It guarantees that you'll never see the errors. Such code has a tendency to make it into production too. If you intend to add logging later, remove the `try/catch` block entirely or at least use `catch{throw;}`

Comment: Your problem is not in the HTTP call; it's where you [block on asynchronous code](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Comment: Instead of calling `.Result` in the controller, use ` bool complete = await WorkingPaperCreator.StartWPCreation();`. You are *blocking* the synchronization context which means that the other `await` statements can't return to it.

Comment: PS - notice how you *forgot* to check the result in your controller? Even if the REST call fails, you'll still return a 200. You don't need the catch blocks, even for logging. The single log statement in the controller action is enough to log all the relevant information

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes you are correct I added those try catch blocks just for debugging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This blocking call leads to the problems:
`bool complete = WorkingPaperCreator.StartWPCreation().Result;`.
You get dead lock. To avoid it use aync\await everywhere (make your controller async as well) or add `.ConfigureAwait(false)` to all await calls.

Comment: Blocking in the controller action will waste the thread the OP was trying to save with `await`. `ConfigureAwait(false)` will remove the block but still waste the tread. It could also cause log4net to lose any attributes stored in the synchronization context