# Get all devices from IoT Azure Hub

Tags: c#, .net, azure, iot, azure-iot-hub

I would like to obtain all devices into my Azure IoT Hub system (connected, not connected, it doesn't matter).

I've read the documentation about the system itself with no result but [Get a list of devices from Azure IoT Hub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44563602/get-a-list-of-devices-from-azure-iot-hub) has become obsolete.

Is there any kind of query which let retrieve all devices associated to my system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the REST API [Service - Query Iot Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/service/queryiothub)

Payload:

```
{
  "query": "SELECT deviceId FROM devices"
}
```

Comment: There's no complete example offered with .net.

Where can I find one?

Comment: Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/#common-parameters-and-headers for common headers such as Content-Type and Authorization. That's all what you need it.

Comment: the root page is **IoT Hub REST** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/ and this page described all common parts such as parameters, headers, etc. for handling IoT Hub by REST APIs located in the subfolder *Reference*, where is linked also the *Service - Query IoT Hub*.

Comment: Btw. example of the query all devices using the C# service SDK is described in  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-query-language, see *C# example*.

Comment: Perfect, what I was looking for is in your second link! I didn't find it: thank you!

Comment: In the case of using only getting the list of all IoT devices, I do recommend to use a REST API (less dependences, etc.)

Comment: It isn't the only use I'll perform, I need also to set trigger above Status update of devices..

Comment: The Link "Service - Query Iot Hub" is broken. Can someone update this?