# Get iothub registered devices via REST API

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-hub-device-management

Hello i am trying to fetch devices present/registered at IOTHUB via RESTAPI. But i am confused how to fetch all devices.
I have read the documentation here : [IoT Hub Service - Get Devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/digitaltwinmodel/service/getdevices)

But When i send a request i am getting an error

"Message": "ErrorCode:IotHubUnauthorizedAccess;Unauthorized",
"ExceptionMessage": "Tracking ID:a795ee1f7ae04adfa600333e45e9aa09-G:5-TimeStamp:06/29/2020 14:32:56"

Is there any auth token to provide in order to get devices?

Comment: Hi, did you have any luck with the answers below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So for a quick start on this we can use Postman with [Azure IoT Hub Query language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-query-language)..+ SAS token for authorization.

**Step 1:** Generate the SAS token as said by Matthijs, Also we can quickly make use of [Device Explorer tool](https://catalog.azureiotsolutions.com/docs?title=Azure/azure-iot-device-ecosystem/manage_iot_hub) Or [Use this link to find the *SetupDeviceExplorer.msi*](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/releases/tag/2016-11-17). Copy the generated SAS token fully.

[image]

**Step 2:** Construct the Query body.

the POST query looks like this sample. See [Registry Manager - Query Iot Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/service/registrymanager/queryiothub)

> POST
> https://IOTHUB.azure-devices.net/devices/query?api-version=2020-03-13

```
{
  "query": "SELECT deviceId FROM devices"
}
```

[image]

**Step 3:** Authorization use SAS token, and send the request to test it out.

[image]

A similar thread answered by RomanKiss can be read from [Get all devices from IoT Azure Hub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56965855/get-all-devices-from-iot-azure-hub).
Please let us know if you know further help!

Answer (score 2):

You can call the rest API using the Shared Access Signature. To get a valid token, you can use the Azure CLI like so:

```
az iot hub generate-sas-token -n <IoT hub name> --policy registryRead
```

This will produce an output like:

```
{
  "sas": "SharedAccessSignature sr=iothubname.azure-devices.net&sig=kPszxZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZAhLTILsVpT0tp5sRSWiDZ0%3D&se=1593446477&skn=registryRead"
}
```

Then you need to use the value of "sas" as your Authorization header when you do your GET request. Curl example:

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://iothubname.azure-devices.net/devices?api-version=2019-07-01-preview' \
--header 'Authorization: SharedAccessSignature sr=iothubname.azure-devices.net&sig=kPszxZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZAhLTILsVpT0tp5sRSWiDZ0%3D&se=1593446477&skn=registryRead'
```