# MVC5 - Deadlock with async Tasks?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, async-await, deadlock

I think my web application is suffering from deadlock when I'm calling YouTube API services, so I want to know how to resolve this in the correct manner.  I suspect it's a similar scenario to the following: [Why does this async action hang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526377/why-does-this-async-action-hang)

Please can somebody advise, in very simple terms, why my web application hangs (see inline comments) and how it should be correctly resolved?  Thanks!

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    YouTubeHelper yth = new YouTubeHelper();
     bool unpublishVideo = yth.UpdateVideoOnYouTube(17, "public").Result;
}

public async Task<bool> UpdateVideoOnYouTube(int propertyId, string publishStatus)
{
.....
    YouTubeService youtubeService = await GetYouTubeService(db);
.....
}

public async Task<YouTubeService> GetYouTubeService(ApplicationDbContext db)
{
....
    if (!await credential.RefreshTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None)) //It hangs here!!
        {
        ....
    }
....
}
```

Comment: await the call to UpdateVideoOnYoutTube method and remove accessing the `Result` proeprty

Comment: But then I think the ActionResult would need to be asynchronous? Is that correct and good practise?

Comment: yes make it `async Task<ActionResult`

Comment: Yep that fixed it.  Thanks for your help....

Answer (score 2):

The deadlock is explained [here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). In summary, your asynchronous methods are needing the ASP.NET request context before they can complete, but the call to `Result` is blocking the ASP.NET request context until the asynchronous methods are already completed.

To avoid the deadlock, don't block on async code. Use `await` instead of `Result`:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
  YouTubeHelper yth = new YouTubeHelper();
  bool unpublishVideo = await yth.UpdateVideoOnYouTube(17, "public");
}
```