# Task<bool> causes Entity Framework to Hang

Tags: c#, entity-framework, async-await

When I change the method signature to be Task Entity Framework hangs at SaveChanges.  Why would this be happening?

This code fails

```
public async Task<bool> SaveAsync(agency agency)
    {
        using (var ctx = new AvnEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                ctx.agencies.Add(agency);
                await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
                return true;
            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

This code works

```
public async Task SaveAsync(agency agency)
    {
        using (var ctx = new AvnEntities())
        {
            try
            {
                ctx.agencies.Add(agency);
                await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm betting it relates to this...  

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526377/why-does-this-async-action-hang

You need to post the code calling this method which is hanging.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As comment by Mick and this post here [Asyn-Hanging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526377/why-does-this-async-action-hang)

I created a deadlock because in my UI thread I was waiting to get Task.Result.