# Bulk Read Images from URL using TPL (Task.WhenAll) goes into deadlock when WebClient gives timeout exception

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, asp.net-core-2.0

I created a .net core 2.0 console application where I am reading image data from URLs and process them.
As images are in bulk, i am doing in threads. Everything works fine but when images does not return any data and throws timeout exception, threads get stuck/hang and does continue. It seems some deadlock but i don't know where exactly.

Below is my code.

```
int batchSize = 25;
int numberOfBatches = xmlProperties.Count() < batchSize ? 1 : ((((xmlProperties.Count() / batchSize) % 1) == 0) ? (xmlProperties.Count() / batchSize)
                                                                    : (xmlProperties.Count() / batchSize) + 1);
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBatches; i++)
{
    Task[] Requests = xmlProperties
                        .Skip(i * batchSize)
                        .Take(batchSize)
                        .Select(l => UploadImage(l.PropertyRefNo, l.Images))
                        .ToArray();
    await Task.WhenAll(Requests); // does not return when UploadImage throws exception in WebClient request.
}

public async Task UploadImage(string PropertyRefNo, List<string> Images)
{
    Images = Images.OrderBy(x => x).Take(10).ToList();          

    var index1 = 0;
    foreach (var item in Images)
    {
        try
        {
            index1 = index1 + 1;
            using (MemoryStream imageStream = await ImageUtilities.GetImageData(item)) // Exception comes here in reading data from URL
            {
                // Do Rest Work
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await AddLog(0, JobStatus.ImageFailedFull.ToString(), ex.ToString(), PropertyRefNo + " : " + item, 0);
        }
    }
}

public static async Task<MemoryStream> GetImageData(string filename)
{
    try
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var data = await client.GetAsync(filename);
            byte[] imageStream = await data.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
            return new MemoryStream(imageStream);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}

public class WebClientWithTimeout : WebClient
{
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        WebRequest wr = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        wr.Timeout = 100000; // 100 seconds
        return wr;
    }
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible that two threads are reading same image or PropertyRefNo is same for two images?

Comment: 1. No thread can read same image. 2. Yes PropertyRefNo number is same for a list of images.

Comment: Basically for any PropertyRefNo, maximum 10 images are processing.

Comment: Those are getting processed in the same thread is that guaranteed?

Comment: Well as per the code, I can only assume it, but not sure 100%. How can I check this and what could be a solution to process them via same thread only.

Comment: Everything works fine when image urls gives data, problem starts when they throws timeout exception and that too in bulk, then only thread gets stuck or lost.

Comment: I assume that two(or many) are trying to save the image on same path.

Comment: Okay, any solution to avoid such condition?

Comment: Either  you need to make sure that two thread do not use same propertyref or use GUID in the image name so that they do not save to same image.

Comment: Let me comment the code for image resize and save and check if only image read is working fine.

Comment: Sure please check and confirm me.

Comment: @Gaurav: It still gets stuck/lost, so problem is not which you're assuming. After approximately 75 timeout exception, it processed 2-3 more working urls and then stuck/lost.

Comment: Your only async action is AddLog() ?? Not GetImageData() ??

Comment: Your code is synchronous unless there is an exception...

Comment: @HenkHolterman, Well I tried that also but no luck so far. Let me update code in my question for that.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, I updated the question, pls check.

Comment: @JitendraPancholi WebClient is obsolete, replaced by HttpClient which is thread-safe out of the box *and* supports timeouts. In any case, `await Task.WhenAll` doesn't deadlock if one of the tasks throws, it would throw itself. It would deadlock if one of the tasks never finishes

Comment: Now you are not awaiting GetImageData(). But this is getting messy. Consider writing a mcve ([mcve]). We can't seed AddLog().

Comment: @JitendraPancholi `GetImageData(item).Result` that's a blocking call on an *asynchronous* method. If you want to download some images in batches, the code can be a *lot* simpler. Perhaps you should explain what you actually want to do, so people can show how it could be done?

Comment: Okay, sorry for my bad code or explanation. I have around 100 XMs and each XML contains many properties (real estate data). Now in each property, we have more than 10 images (as URL). Now I have to read each XML, save all properties into DB and read all images, resize and save to azure blobs.

Comment: I modified my code as per you both and checking if that helps. But really thanks to you both for replying.

Comment: Pls check updated code.

Comment: Excellent, it worked. I replaced webclient with HttpClient and also used await for GetImageData method. Can you please post your solution, I'll mark that as answer, so others can also be get benefit.