# StreamReader await ReadLineAsync blocks execution

Tags: c#

I have the following code in a desktop application :

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("path\\to\\file.csv"))
{
    string line;
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        line = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
        string[] values = line.Split(',');
        double.TryParse(values[pointsIndex], out double points);
    }
}
```

The line `line = await reader.ReadLineAsync()` blocks the the program entirely and makes the application unresponsive.
While debugging I noticed that it is runs 4 times and then blocks indefinitely.

This code is very simple and correct AFAIK. Why is it not working as expected?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change it to

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("path\\to\\file.csv"))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = await reader.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
    {
     string[] values = line.Split(',');
     double.TryParse(values[pointsIndex], out double points);
    }
}
```

When it hits end - result will be null and terminate.
See the relative documentation  [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readlineasync?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Doesn't work, still blocks indefinitely at ReadLineAsync.

Comment: add Console.WriteLine(line); in while loop right before splitting to see where it stops.

Comment: I used a break-point and debugging shows that it blocks at ```line = await reader.ReadLineAsync()```

Comment: I think there's issue somewhere else in code - the current code should work just fine. Alternatively you can try to change "using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText("path\\to\\file.csv"))" and see if it helps.

Comment: Also you might want to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526377/why-does-this-async-action-hang

Comment: Thanks, this question helped a lot to understand the problem. It was a deadlock indeed. ```ReadLineAsync().ConfigureAwait(false)``` solves the problem.

Comment: Glad it helped.