# Asynchronously download and compile list of JsonDocument

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, concurrency

I'm a little new (returning after a couple of decades) to C# and to the async/await model of programming.  Looking for a little guidance, since I received an understandable warning CS1998 that the asynchronous method lacks await and operators and will run synchronously.

The code below I think is straightforward - the server API returns data in pages of 25 items.  I'm using a continuation to add each page of 25 to a List of JsonDocuments.  Calling code will handle the parsing as needed.  I'm not sure how I could reasonably leverage anything further in this, but looking for any suggestions/guidance.

```
internal static async Task<List<JsonDocument>> Get_All_Data(HttpClient client, string endpoint)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Downloading all data from {0}{1}", client.BaseAddress, endpoint);
    var all_pages = new List<JsonDocument>();

    // Get first page to determine total number of pages
    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(endpoint).Result;
    Console.WriteLine("Initial download complete - parsing headers to determine total pages");
    //int items_per_page; 
    if (int.TryParse(Get_Header_Value("X-Per-Page", response.Headers), out int items_per_page) == false)
        //     throw new Exception("Response missing X-Per-Page in header");
        items_per_page = 25;


    if (int.TryParse(Get_Header_Value("X-Total-Count", response.Headers), out int total_items) == false)
        //throw new Exception("Response missing X-Total-Count in header");
        total_items = 1;

    // Divsion returns number of complete pages, add 1 for partial IF total items_json is not an exact multiple of items_per_page
    var total_pages = total_items / items_per_page;
    if ((total_items % items_per_page) != 0) total_pages++;

    Console.WriteLine("{0} pages to be downloaded", total_pages);

    var http_tasks = new Task[total_pages];
    for (int i = 1; i <= total_pages; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Downloading page {0}", i);
        var paged_endpoint = endpoint + "?page=" + i;
        response = client.GetAsync(paged_endpoint).Result;
        http_tasks[i - 1] = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ContinueWith((_content) => { all_pages.Add(JsonDocument.Parse(_content.Result)); }); ;
        //http_tasks[i].ContinueWith((_content) => { all_pages.Add(JsonDocument.Parse_List(_content.Result)); });
    }
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAll(http_tasks);  // wait for all of the downloads and parsing to complete

    return all_pages;
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: `client.GetAsync(endpoint).Result;` terrible idea ... you should use `await` instead `Result` ... and do it consistently ... so forget about `ContinueWith` and replace this with another `await`

Comment: What .NET platform are you targeting? .NET 7?

Comment: the warning is saying that your method is async, but you are not awaiting any calls. either remove async, and use ```.Result``` (depending on your circumstances, but as @Selvin mention, it's bad idea. still works.) or ```await client.GetAsync(endpoint)``` and check if result is not null.

Comment: and remove `Task.WaitAll` ... then  `http_tasks` is not needed at all - just use `all_pages.Add(await JsonDocument.Parse(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()))` ... isn't it cleanest ?

Comment: also, if this code and whatever calling it lives on different assembly, don't forget to add `ConfigureAwait(false)` - see [past problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14527164). have been there and got a lot of downvotes (lol).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, yes, .NET 7

Comment: @JanatbekOrozaly, I realize that I'm not awaiting anything in this function, as written.  My understanding was that I need to add the async operator if I want to call this function asynchronously with await.

Comment: @Selvin, did you mean `all_pages.Add( JsonDocument.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()))`?  As written, it wouldn't compile.

Comment: yes .. I forgot about `JsonDocument.Parse` and added it in edit but at wrong place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to `await` all asynchronous operations, and use the [`Parallel.ForEachAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync) method to parallelize the downloading of the JSON documents, while maintaining control of the degree of parallelism:

```
static async Task<JsonDocument[]> GetAllData(HttpClient client, string endpoint)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(endpoint);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    if (!Int32.TryParse(GetHeaderValue(response, "X-Total-Count"),
        out int totalItems) || totalItems < 0)
            totalItems = 1;

    if (!Int32.TryParse(GetHeaderValue(response, "X-Per-Page"),
        out int itemsPerPage) || itemsPerPage < 1)
            itemsPerPage = 25;

    int totalPages = ((totalItems - 1) / itemsPerPage) + 1;
    
    JsonDocument[] results = new JsonDocument[totalPages];
    ParallelOptions options = new() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5 };
    
    await Parallel.ForEachAsync(Enumerable.Range(1, totalPages), options,
        async (page, ct) =>
    {
        string pageEndpoint = endpoint + "?page=" + page;
        HttpResponseMessage pageResponse = await client
            .GetAsync(pageEndpoint, ct);
        pageResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        string pageContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(ct);
        JsonDocument result = JsonDocument.Parse(pageContent);
        results[page - 1] = result;
    });
    return results;
}

static string GetHeaderValue(HttpResponseMessage response, string name)
    => response.Headers.TryGetValues(name, out var values) ?
        values.FirstOrDefault() : null;
```

The [`MaxDegreeOfParallelism`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism) is configured to the value `5` for demonstration purposes. You can find the optimal degree of parallelism by experimenting with your API. Setting the value too low might result in mediocre performance. Setting the value too high might overburden the target server, and potentially trigger an anti-DoS-attack mechanism.

If you are not familiar with the [`Enumerable.Range`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range), it is a LINQ method that returns an incremented numeric sequence of integers that starts from `start`, and contains `count` elements.

The `GetAllData` is an asynchronous method and it is supposed to be `await`ed. If you are calling it without `await`, and your application is a UI application like WinForms or WPF, you are at risk of [experiencing a deadlock](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). Don't panic, it happens consistently, and you'll observe it during the testing. One way to prevent it is to append `.ConfigureAwait(false)` to all awaited operations inside the `GetAllData` method.